# No default for field with auto increment after renaming

Tags: mysql, knex.js

I need to rename one of my tables and one of the column in this table.

I've done it with knex migration next way:

```
.alterTable('tableToRename', table => {
    table.dropForeign('id_reference1');
    table.dropForeign('id_reference2');
})
.alterTable('relatedTable1', table => {
    table.dropForeign('tableToRename_id_col');
})
.renameTable('tableToRename', 'newName')
.alterTable('newName', table => {
    table.renameColumn('tableToRename_id_col', 'tableToRename_new_id_col');
})
.alterTable('relatedTable1', table => {
    table.renameColumn('tableToRename_id_col', 'tableToRename_new_id_col');
    table.foreign('tableToRename_new_id_col').references('newName.tableToRename_new_id_col');
})
.alterTable('newName', table => {
    table.foreign('id_reference1').references('table3');
    table.foreign('id_reference2').references('table4');
})
```

So now when i try to add new record to **newName** table - next error appears:

**Error(1366) HY000: "Incorrect integer value:" for column "tableToRename_new_id_col" at row 1"**

How to rename auto integer column with id in correct way?

Server response with next error: 
  code: 'ER_NO_DEFAULT_FOR_FIELD',
  errno: 1364,
  sqlMessage: 'Field \'tableToRename_new_id_col\' doesn\'t have a default value',
  sqlState: 'HY000',
  index: 0,

**UPD.** Previously I've created a table that i want to rename like this:

```
.createTableIfNotExists('tableToRename', tab => {
          t.charset('utf8mb4');
          table.bigincrements('tableToRename_id_col')
            .unsigned()
            .primary()
            .notNullable();
          table.bigint('id_reference1')
            .notNullable()
            .unsigned()
            .references('id_reference1')
            .inTable('table_reference1');
          table.bigint('id_reference2')
            .notNullable()
            .unsigned()
            .references('id_reference2')
            .inTable('table_reference2');
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is mysql setting when you want to insert a new position without having all data.

You can configure your mysql to set NULL if you don't send values.
temporary solution (until you restart the server):
SET @@GLOBAL.sql_mode= 'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';

or you can set it in you my.ini file.
Here are mode details: http://webnetkit.com/error-sqlstatehy000-general-error-1366-incorrect-integer-value-for-column/

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bug in knex. If you haven't done it already, you should send bug report to knex issues. Until then you might be able to work around it by setting new id column to auto increment manually. Also you can check out what kind of queries are generated there with .toSQL().

One thing that would be good to have would be complete reproduction case, where you first create table and then alter it and show that it is failing. That way someone can figure out the exact problem easier.

Comment: Thank you! New id column helps!
Now i'm wating for knex response